# Offline Custom Tiled Google Map with Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, cordova

I have a custom made tile for google map. Works perfectly fine online, but when I turn off data on my phone, it just shows the loading icon, as it can't communicate with google.

As I have my own tiles, is it possible to use google maps offline with phonegap?

Comment: It could take a lot of effort to make it work offline if you are using the Google Maps API, the requests are designed to be sent and received through the HTTP protocol, while you can change it to go through FILE, it would just generate a lot of cross-domain errors - which technically PhoneGap can ignore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to use Google's API offline.  However, If you have your own tiles, and have them embedded within your application archive, you could use Leaflet to render the local tiles.  http://leafletjs.com/   If your custom tiles are remote (hosted on a server), then you're still not going to be able to consume them in an offline scenario.

Comment: I'll check out leafletJS. My tiles are all offline, and I spliced them myself. Thanks!